# Make a threadDelay-like function in Parsec - Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lisp, parsec

I have been making my own Lisp-y language using Parsec in Haskell over the last few weeks, following the ["Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours) guide. Note that I am still a beginner at Haskell.

I'm trying to implement a "sleep" function that waits a certain time then prints "true" after the command has been inputted at the REPL, using my custom types from Parsec (I am not using a lexer/tokens). The problem is is that when I input the `delay` function into the REPL, it just shows "done" instead of suspending the thread. Also, I'm using "Control.Monad.Error" instead of "Control.Monad.Except" because the tutorial is using Error.

Here are my types (compressed for convenience):

```hs
-- All the custom data types, which follows the syntax: [Name - Haskell Type]
data Values = Atom String
         | Number Integer
         | InOut (IO ()) 
         | IOFunc ([Values] -> IOThrowsError Values) -- This is used for File and REPL IO

instance Show Values where show = showVal
```

This is my "show" function (compressed for convenience):

```hs
showVal :: Values -> String
showVal (InOut _) = "done"
showVal (IOFunc _) = "<primitive>"
```

Finally, the function:

```hs
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

dTime :: [Values] -> IOThrowsError Values
dTime [Number n] = 
    let delay' = fromIntegral n
    in (return . InOut) (threadDelay delay')
```

REPL output:

```lisp
BuBBLE> (delay 1000) ; it works partially, but it immediately outputs `done`
done
```

Does threadDelay only work in GHC, or what am I missing to make it work?

Full source: [Ninjacop/BuBBLE](https://github.com/Ninjacop/BuBBLE/)

Comment: Is the value `1000` is getting passed unchanged to `dTime`?  Because `threadDelay` takes microseconds so you would only be pausing for a millisecond.

Comment: The terms 'delay' and 'dTime' do not appear in the "full source" you link.  Please make questions self contained including a runnable MCVE.

Answer (score 3):

`dTime` yields a value that *contains* an `IO` action which, if you executed it, would suspend the thread. Good. But `showVal` never attemps executing any `IO` – it just sees, “there is an `IO` action here”, but doesn't do anything with it. In fact it *can't* do anything with it, due to the pure signature `-> String`. To make it eval too, you'll probably want to use `evalString :: Env -> String -> IO String` or something instead.

Comment: I have the exact same function `evalString` in my code, are you saying that I should apply it to `dTime`?

Comment: You should apply it to `(delay 1000)`, if you want the delay to happen.